# Create a Desk top short cut icon to my Web page

Tags: safari

I want to create a shot cut icon for my web page on the home screen.If a user drag this icon to his desktop , he can directly access my web page.Is possible to safari and Mac machines.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers have this functionality built in already. Users can drag the favicon from beside the address bar to the desktop.